# convert JSON data to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, json

The response from REST server is JSON format. I need to put result into MySql database via java coding. I don't know how to deal with this.

Basically, we use JDBC connect to Mysql for add, delete, and updata, but this time the first thing is retrieve the RESTful server, then store results into database. And the result is JSON format, for instance:
JSON response

```
{   "columns": "score",   "reportList": [
    {
      "rowCount": 8063,
      "rowList": [
        "2013-07-09,20:00:00,73.2,",
        "2013-07-09,20:05:00,73.3,",
        "2013-07-09,20:10:00,73.4,",
        "2013-07-09,20:15:00,73.4,",
        "2013-07-09,20:20:00,73.5,",
               ...
               ...
      ]
    }   
],   
"startDate": "2013-07-10",   
"endDate": "2013-08-06",   
"status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": ""   
} }
```

From the result, the columns:"timestamp" and "score" are my table column, and the rowList: 2013-07-09 and 73.2 are the value of column. These variable and value is what I need. so how to map the json then get the valuable data, put into database finally.

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for focusing on this post. Sure, this response is got from RESTful tools. after got results, I know what I need. Then I already set mysql server. Create the database structure in mysql. use JDBC to connect mysql. So there are only two challenge left, 1. retrieve specific data via calling restful by using java not tools. the second is put JSON into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JSON.org website (http://json.org/java/)
It looks like you can parse the response into a Java Object or an Array and pull the values from there to pass to the JDBC.

```
JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.readFrom( string )
```

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java
http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html
http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON library to extract the data out.  Then use JDBC to insert it into your database.  At least that's the lowest level way to do it.  You haven't said what tools you're using.

Comment: There is public RESTful api. Mysql is in my laptop. And I am planing to write java connect Rest server and mysql. There are two challenges for me is retrieve specific data via calling restful. the second is put JSON into database.

Comment: OK well what I'm saying will work.